# C++ Pass variable of unknown name to method

Tags: c++, file, variables, methods

Is there a way in c++ to pass to a method a variable where that variable could be one of several different variables (of same type) depending on where the method is called.

For example:

A method to check if a file exists with the correct name.

At one point in the program, I might want to check a users file exists, so the user enters their username into string variable username, and that is passed to CheckFile:

```
bool LotterySystem::CheckFile(const std::string &USERNAME)
{
    //if file exists, return false, else return true
    FILE *fin = fopen((USERNAME + ".txt").c_str(), "r");
    if (fin)
    {
        fclose(fin);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

At another point I might want to check a file with stock information exists, so the user enters the stock they wish to check into string variable stockType:

```
bool LotterySystem::CheckFile(const std::string &STOCKTYPE)
{
    //if file exists, return false, else return true
    FILE *fin = fopen((STOCKTYPE + ".txt").c_str(), "r");
    if (fin)
    {
        fclose(fin);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Is there a way to pass a generic string variable with any name, to CheckFile, without having to have different CheckFile methods for every file name to be checked?

Comment: Both of those functions do exactly the same thing.

Comment: You have a fundamental misunderstanding of how parameters are passed to methods and functions.

Comment: The parameter name is completely unrelated to the name of the variable you pass to it. The main point of *having* procedures with parameters in a language is that you can pass different things to them.

Comment: your compiler doesn't know English

Answer (score 1):

You don't need differnt `CheckFile` methods. In fact, having more than one would result in a multiple definition error, because you are defining two methods with the same signature.

Just call it with different arguments:

```
LotterySystem ls;
ls.CheckFile("MyNameIsFred");
ls.CheckFile("MyPreferredPreferredStockName");
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to pass different values of type `const std::string`, which in C++ can be passed simply using a single function. You will have to change the value which you are calling the function, not create different instances of the `bool LotterySystem::CheckFile` method.

And also, no compiler would compile the two instances of the same function, with same parameters.

```
bool LotterySystem::CheckFile(const std::string &USERNAME)
{
    //if file exists, return false, else return true
    FILE *fin = fopen((USERNAME + ".txt").c_str(), "r");
    if (fin)
    {
        fclose(fin);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Then call:

```
LotterySystem mySystem;
std::string sName = "John Doe", sStockName = "ZXY";
bool nameFileExists = mySystem.CheckFile(sName);
bool stockFileExists = mySystem.CheckFile(sStockName);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to alter the semantics of the function by changing the name in the signature. That's not how it works. As chris states in the comments, the function's semantics stay the same, no matter what `string` you pass - only the return value will  change, depending on what functions used in `CheckFile` return. Giving the string a different name does *not* create another overload of `CheckFile` and will not, in any way, alter the semantics or code flow within the function.

What you want is a dedicated function per purpose. `CheckFile` should just do what the name suggests(well, sort of): check whether the `txt` file denoted by the `string` you pass exists.

Layered on `CheckFile` you might want to implement additional functionality for the purpose of checking different types of files. That being said, if you're dealing with text-files, you need to parse and validate the contents anyway to be sure you actually have a valid user file or a stock-info file. In essence, you want something like this:

```
bool IsUserFile(const std::string&); // validates text-file contents

bool processUserFile(const std::string& path) // path omitting the extension '.txt'
{
  if(!(CheckFile(path) && IsUserFile(path)))
    return false;

  // open file process contents
  // return true if successful, false otherwise      
}
```

Similarly for stock-info files.

On another note, there is no need to make such a function a *member function* of `LotterySystem` and if you insist on making it a member function, consider making it a `static` member function - it doesn't depend on an instance of `LotterySystem`.

Also, if I understand your intentions correctly, you want to check if a file exists. So, your `CheckFile` function needs to return `true` if it can open the file. Currently, it does exactly the opposite. Leave a comment if I'm mistaken.

Please note: checking for the existence of a file only by seeing if your application can open it is a very restricted case. It might exist and `fopen()` might still not be able to open it, be it due to insufficient privileges or other conditions.